# How to wrap a core data element's attribute in a @Published wrapper?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

When creating a Core Data App, is there any way to wrap an attribute of a Core Data element under the @Published wrapper?

When passing elements to different views, I need to make use of the objectWillChange.send() function, but I was wondering if there is a way to reflect changes on elements through the @Published wrapper.

If so, where should one add the @Published wrapper?

Thank you

Comment: This is not necessary. `NSManagedObject` conforms to `ObservableObject` and `@NSManaged` attributes do publish. Be aware that `@State` and `@Binding` is for value types. You have to use the reference type counterparts.